# How to generate a single translation file for a large Qt project?

Tags: qt, internationalization, qmake

I have a large project with one qmake project file defining all project components using a 'subdirs' template. Currently I define translation files in the qmake files of each sub-project. This results in separate translation files for each sub-project, which quickly becomes too cumbersome to maintain.

How do I get lupdate to produce a single translation file containing all translation strings for all of the sub-projects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all split all your *pro files* into *pro* and *pri* files. Then put all the *pri* files into one global *pro file* and generate the language file for that pro file.

Special language pro file looks like this:

```
TEMPLATE = app
DEPENDPATH +=  Proj1 Proj2 Proj3    

include(Proj1/Proj1.pri)  
include(Proj2/Proj2.pri)
include(Proj3/Proj3.pri)

TRANSLATIONS = en.ts fr.ts it.main.ts ja.main.ts nl.main.ts
```

A script can easily generate this project language file for you.

Comment: I just tried your solution assuming I need to specify only the SOURCES, HEADERS, and FORMS in the .pri file, and it works! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What goes into the pri files?

Comment: @BenJones, the `.pri` files are just `.pro` files that are included by another `.pro` file. So the difference in extension is just to indicate that they are included. This separation allows having one `.pro` file that combines all your sources from which to generate the translations.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is pretty old but I will still append my solution. This ends up with several single translation files, but this is what I actually wanted to reach.You can then run `lupdate` on the main project file and it will generate/update the .ts files in every subdir.

Therefore, in every pro file you must specify a `TARGET` and this project has to be in a folder with exactly this name.

In every project file I included one shared pri file:

```sh
# Including shared configurations
!include(../common/shared.pri) {
  error(shared.pri not found)
}
```

Then, in this pri file:

```sh
# Including traslations for every language
exists($$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/translations/) {
    TRANSLATIONS += $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/translations/$${TARGET}_de_DE.ts
    message(> Found Translations for $${TARGET}: $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/translations/$${TARGET}_de_DE.ts)
}
```

For more translated languages you can add a little bit of logic.